# Detect if model change in Vue was triggered by user interaction or programatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have some trouble with Vue's reactivity and my custom component in Quasar 2. Here's the basic use case:

- The component provides two radio buttons and a select dropdown.
- Whenever the user changes one of the radio selection, then the select dropdown will be reset to `null`.

This works fine. However, the user can also click a button which will overwrite any selection with new values for the radio button and the select dropdown. And here comes the problem: This button will replace the `v-model` for the component. Then, the watcher for the radio button will trigger and reset the select dropdown.

**Example:**
User selects "Domestic" and "Option 1", then clicks the "Overwrite" button. This shall result in "International" with "Option 2", but as the watcher fires, "Option 2" will be reset.

Here is a StackBlitz:
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-adtenr?file=src/components/MySelectComponent.vue)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overwrite` property on button click:

```
function overwriteModel() {
  model.value = {
    origin: 'international',
    selectedOption: 'Option 2',
    overwrite: true
  };
}
```

and reset it in watcher:

```
watch(
  () => localModel.value.origin,
    (newOrigin, oldOrigin) => {
      if (newOrigin !== oldOrigin && !localModel.value.overwrite) {
        localModel.value.selectedOption = null;
      } localModel.value.overwrite = false
  }
);
```

and in `domestic` q-radio:

```
<q-radio 
  v-model="localModel.origin" 
  val="domestic" 
  label="Domestic"   
  @click="localModel.overwrite = false" 
/>
```

[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-ctcv6k)